# MediaBrowserCompat.Connect() always call onConnectionFailed() callback

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am building a android media player which will play a radio stream from URL. 
Piece of code are as follows:

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarCastActivity implements MediaBrowserProvider {
private MediaBrowserCompat mMediaBrowser;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMediaBrowser = new MediaBrowserCompat(this,
            new ComponentName(this, MusicService.class), mConnectionCallback, null);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mMediaBrowser.connect();
}

private final MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback mConnectionCallback =
    new MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected() {
            //setSupportMediaController code
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");
        }
    }; 
}
```

Here `MusicService` is the service which extends `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` and yes, put the following code in the manifest:

```
<service
android:name=".playback.RadioPlayerService"
android:exported="true"
tools:ignore="ExportedService">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
</intent-filter>
```

After running the app, it always call `onConnectionFailed` callback method. But found no way to discover actual reason for connection failed. Any idea how to find the error?

Answer (score 4):

Replying to this as I was just running into the same issue where I kept getting the onConnectionFailed result. It turns out that the solution was that I forgot to update the name of the service in my AndroidManifest.xml.

I think the problem may be similar here. You do have a service declared in your manifest, however, the name is set to '.playback.RadioPlayerService' and when creating your MediaBrowser, you're referencing 'MediaService.class'. Try replacing

```
android:name=".playback.RadioPlayerService"
```

with

```
android:name=".MusicService"
```

or, alternatively, update your instantiation of the MediaBrowser to reference RadioPlayerService.class if that exists.

Answer (score 4):

Got in a similar situation, where the connection always failed because of below;

> 2020-01-11 18:17:33.760 10560-10560/com.demo.package
>   I/MediaBrowserService: No root for client com.your.package.name from
>   service android.service.media.MediaBrowserService$ServiceBinder$1

which caused the ***onConnectionFailed*** to be called on my controller activity.

It was happening because i was using the default override implementation of onGetRoot[MediaBrowserServiceCompat] which ultimately caused this issue :

```
@Nullable
@Override
public BrowserRoot onGetRoot(@NonNull String clientPackageName, int clientUid, @Nullable Bundle rootHints) {

    return null;
}
```

this implementation must return a BrowserRoot object with a unique root id instead of null.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public BrowserRoot onGetRoot(@NonNull String clientPackageName, int clientUid, @Nullable Bundle rootHints) {

    Log.d("MEDIA_BROWSER_SERVICE_COMPAT","onGetRoot() called");

    return new BrowserRoot(
            'YOUR_UNIQUE_MEDIA_ROOT_ID',
            null);
}
```

YOUR_UNIQUE_MEDIA_ROOT_ID is a unique string identifier that needs to be passed along, creating a new BrowserRoot for your controller hook.